# Flutter Firebase Functions Error: Database not defined

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I've created a delete oldFiles function for my Database that deletes nodes from my chat messages.  I've used the example function provided by Firebase and updated it to fit my use. My database structure is `databaseName/messages/{pushId}` and I've added const `functions = require('firebase-functions')` and `const admin = require('firebase-admin')` and `admin.initializeApp()`. Here is what I have...

```
exports.deleteOldItems = functions.database.ref('messages/{pushId}').onWrite(async (change) => {
  const ref = change.after.ref.parent; // reference to the parent
  const now = Date.now();
  const cutoff = (DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch - CUT_OFF_TIME);
  const oldItemsQuery = ref.orderByChild('timestamp').endAt(cutoff);
  const snapshot = await oldItemsQuery.once('value');
  // create a map with all children that need to be removed

  const updates = {};
  snapshot.forEach(child => {
    updates[child.key] = null;
  });
  // execute all updates in one go and return the result to end the function
  return ref.update(updates);
});
```

When I review my Function logs, I'm getting the following errors...

> ReferenceError: DateTime is not defined
>       at exports.deleteOldItems.functions.database.ref.onWrite (/srv/index.js:17:18)
>       at cloudFunction (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:131:23)
>       at /worker/worker.js:825:24
>       at 
>       at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)

And my Functions are finishing with status: error.  Any ideas to what may be going on?

Answer (score 0):

DateTime isn't a valid JavaScript object or identifier.  If you want to work with dates and times, you will need to work with Date, as you are in the line just above where you have DateTime.  You should probably review the JavaScript documentation for [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to learn how it works.